# Golang routing in different controllers

Tags: go

I am new to Golang and I am trying to learn how to do efficient routing. For instance I have a controller folder/directory and inside that controller I want to have different Func/methods with their own unique routes but I do not know how to do that. I have downloaded the **github.com/gorilla/mux** package and my application looks like this
[image]

The main section of my application looks like this and it is working perfectly: ***tim.go***

```
package main

import(
    "net/http"
    "fmt"
    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
)


func HomeHandler(writer http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    writer.WriteHeader(200)
    fmt.Fprintf(writer, "Home!!!\n")
}
func main() {
    r := mux.NewRouter()
    r.HandleFunc("/home", HomeHandler).Name("bob")
         http.Handle("/",r)
    http.ListenAndServe(":8000", nil)
}
```

The issue is how can I get the func/methods inside my Controller file(s) to also display on the browser. My **sample.go** file does not show in the browser when I go to that URL

```
package Controllers



import(
    "net/http"
    "fmt"
    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
)


func HomeHandler(writer http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    writer.WriteHeader(200)
    fmt.Fprintf(writer, "New Home")
}
func main() {
    r := mux.NewRouter()
    r.HandleFunc("/new", HomeHandler).Name("bob")
    http.Handle("/",r)
    http.ListenAndServe(":8000/new", nil)
}
```

When I go into my browser and type **localhost:8000/new** it says file not found. Any suggestions would be great

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you run the `tim.go` file to start the server.

If so, the problem is you don't have the route you're calling `/new`, you should have an answer with `/home`.

To do it, you should move your `HomeHandler` function to `Controllers` package and then import this package in your main ad instantiate the routes you need.

Hope this helps.